# How do I print out the value in the matrix that the list is indicating

Tags: python

Sorry if this code is bad, I'm quite new to coding.
 
So I want the code to print out the value at row 3 col 4 instead of printing out rows 2 and 3.

```
import numpy as np 
w = 8
l = 5
s = 2
board = np.arange(w*l)
board = board.reshape(l,w)
start = board[s,0]
currentpoint = start
print(board)
print()

def block_a(currentpoint):
  currentpoint = np.argwhere(board == currentpoint) + [0, 3]
  return currentpoint

currentpoint = np.hstack(block_a(currentpoint))
print(currentpoint)
print(board[currentpoint]) 


Expected : 19

Actual :   

[[16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23]

[24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31]]
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment *currentpoint* is a two item array [2, 3]. When you index your board using this array, this is equivalent to using *board[[2,3]]*. Which will return an array of 'rows' 2 and 3.

```
print(board[currentpoint])
print("... and ...")
print(board[[2,3]]

[[16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23]
[24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31]]
... and ...
[[16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23]
[24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31]]
```

To access **19** you instead need to index your board like **board[x][y]** or **board[x,y]**, which is directly asking for item x of board and item y of x.
 To do this, you can use the following which directly translates to currentpoint[2,3].

```
print(board[currentpoint[0], currentpoint[1]])
print("... and ...")
print(board[2,3])

19
... and ...
19
```

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but do you mind explaining why that works?